# How to link to an element with id on another page from homepage in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter and want to internally link my a tag on homepage to element with id="gainers" on products page.

I have tried many sources on the net, documentation of CodeIgniter (Views), and videos on youtube but could not get help. My controller has this code.

```
 public function toLoadProductsPageGainers()
    {
       $this->load->view('vsc_spl_product_from_model#gainers');
    }
```

where "gainers" is the id of a segment on the products page.

I want the link which is calling toLoadProductsPageGainers() from my homepage to lead to id="gainers" on the products page. But 404 error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html code should be

```
<a href="<?=site_url("toLoadProductsPageGainers/#gainers")?>">Go To Link</a>
```

While your controller should be like below

```
public function toLoadProductsPageGainers()
{
   $this->load->view('vsc_spl_product_from_model');
}
```